# How to construction names of list with paste when using names()

Tags: r

This first example shows a large list with the elements: "3.13" "3.3" "3.47" from a split dataframe based on the VDD1 col:

```
>Data_Char_VDD1 <- split(Data_Char, Data_Char$VDD1)
```

Looking up names of elements in the large list "Data_Char_VDD1" would look like this:

```
>names(Data_Char_VDD1)
[1] "3.13" "3.3" "3.47"
```

I want to look up names in several lists, how many will differ from time to time. Lets say it is 4 this time.

I am trying to do something like this, which should create 4 variables called VDD1..4 containing their respective VDD combinations:

```
for(i in 1:length(Configuration$VDDlist[!is.na(Configuration$VDDlist)])){
  assign(paste0("VDD",i), names(paste0("Data_Char_VDD",i)))
}
```

Resulting in 4 empty variables.

Debugging shows that my method of getting names from lists where the names are constructed using paste0 does not work:

```
>i <- 2
>names(paste0("Data_Char_VDD",i))
NULL
```

How can I construct names in the correct data format in a way so it is useful to function names() ?

Comment: rawr, sorry the question got a bit long, so it was easy to miss the point. My point was that I have up to 4 of those large list called Data_Char_VDD1..4 derived from splits of Data_Char depending on how many VDD cols I have in my dataset.

Comment: It is not clear what are you using `assign` here for. It is clear that you probably shouldn't. Can we have a reproducible example please?

Comment: `name` is a special attribute, which you do not assign. You just create a character vector of length one and expect it to have a name. `x <- paste0("var", 1); names(x) <- "myname"; names(x)`.

Comment: You code would work fine if you just didn't call `names` on your `paste0(...)`. Also, consider carefully whether you actually want to assign variables programmatically, it is often a bad idea. You have to access them using `get`, it is just a pain.

Comment: My goal is to have 1 variable for each large list containing a list of elements in that large list. I know that for() sentences can give me a jail sentence and I try to avoid them, when I can find other ways. But this got me quickly where I needed to be. My boss tells me: "dont make art, make it work and progress" ;-)

Comment: @Xillur You can use a screwdriver to put a nail into the wall (and run the risk to hurt yourself or the nail). Or you can learn to use a hammer and really get productive.

Comment: I think `setNames` would be the best way. This allows you to define an object and its names in one fell swoop.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try :

```
names(eval(parse(text=paste0("Data_Char_VDD",i))))
```

Comment: If you need this, you are doing it wrong. See [fortune 106](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/fortunes/vignettes/fortunes.pdf).

Comment: How ugly. You can just set the name of a vector using the `names<-` function. And it is likely that he should not even actually use any of this to solve his _actual_ problem.